# Cannot access the web server error on Glassfish v3

Tags: glassfish, blazeds

I have developed a web application in Eclipse 3.6 on GlassFish v3 and i am trying to add a FlexProject to it.

I have deployed Dlazeds on Glassfish and i followed this tutorial to create a flex project :  http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/setting-up-blazeds/

I changed the web.xml file to match the schema but when i try to create a new Flex Project i get this warning :

"Cannot access the web server. The server root folder or root URL may be invalid"

I cannot figure out the problem,i have googled it but i didn't get any answers.

Can you help me please ? It's really frustrating.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best article describing how to setup a Flex/Java project is on Mihai [blog](http://corlan.org/2008/06/05/creating-a-combined-flexjava-project-in-flex-builder-wo-lcdsblazeds/), in case you did not already found it. The steps done by Flex Builder in order to validate the server root are:

1)Check if the server root exists

2)Check if services.xml or flex-config.xml exists

3)Creates a temporary file and checks for it with a GET command on the
server port.